# Sharepoint Web Application

Tags: database, sharepoint, restore

We are really in a mess. The following is what happened.

1. We have taken backup of WSS_Content database.
2. From Central Administration Page we remove the database.
3. Added a new database for the website.

Now we are getting the below error

HTTP/1.1 404 
Connection: close
Date: Wed, 07 Apr 2010 10:04:54 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 12.0.0.4518

Even replacing the database not helping. Can someone help us??

Answer (score 3):

I don't get it. 
You removed the database (which mean you removed all sites in the DB), and now you get a "site not found" message.
This is expected.

If you want a new site collection just create it. If you want all old sites back, add the WSS_Content back.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the content database from Central Administration does not delete the database from SQL, it simply removes the connection from the database to the SharePoint farm.  If the database is still in SQL (which it is unless you did something else you didn't mention) then all you have to do is to add a new content database in Central Administration.

If you give it the same name as an existing database (WSS_Content in your case) then it will find the existing one and attach it instead of creating a new one.  So it should be a pretty simple fix.

The error message you are getting is because SharePoint cannot find the specified site because it doesn't know where the content database is.